# Where can I buy a souvenir stamp while traveling in European cities?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, passport-stamps, souvenirs

Since the establishment of Schengen region, there will not be any immigration officer to stamp the passport while traveling within Schengen region. But I would still like to have collect some kind of stamps that I can keep as souvenirs when I travel between different countries. I was thinking that if I can collect the city stamps/seals instead.

I do not intend to have those stamp in my passport, since they might be interpret as mutilation of the passport. Instead I am planning to get a booklet to collect these ink stamps.

e.g. I was hoping of a ink stamp version of the logo when I visit Copenhagen

[image: City of Copenhagen]

Has anyone try anything similar when they were travelling inside/outside Schengen region? Where should I be able to get these stamps when I am visiting a city? This is my first time me and my friends plan and go to travel by ourselves, we got no experience of that, so any kind of suggestions and comments are welcome!

Comment: Where did you get the Copenhagen stamp? I think buying a stamp and postcard and then sending it to yourself would be easier and have seen many people do it. A lot popular in Venice and Vatican.

Comment: I believe that border officials are still **allowed** to give entry or exit stamps to confirm the passage of borders. At least that was the case a couple of decades ago ...

Comment: I will not put this as an answer but you can collect the coat of arms for all the major european cities on ebay.  Just enter something like "city of Hamburg Coat of Arms". Or "Denmark Postage Stamps" Collecting them before you leave might dampen the fun but it assures that your collection is authentic and complete.

Comment: [Youth hostels stamps](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-tW5CUo-o-mg/VXgNWjvIiUI/AAAAAAAAgoI/CBsFyodj-TU/s1600/Afewpics%2B078.jpg) used to be common; however, you may not have much luck nowadays except for the older YI or YHA establishments; it seems to have fallen out of backpacking culture.

Comment: @GayotFow can you explain what form those coat of arms you are talking about? Is it just an ink stamp, or some kind of lapel pin etc.?

Comment: All shapes and forms, check http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/European-Travel-Commission-PRINT-AD-1959-Europe-Coat-of-Arms-/191777391780?hash=item2ca6d2c4a4:g:zS4AAOSwX~dWjt8J as an example

Comment: @o.m They certainly should not give you a standard Schengen entry or exit stamp, not at an internal border (and stamps security code have to be registered in a way that can be traced to an individual border guard). Would they have some sort of novelty stamp just for this purpose?

Comment: @Relaxed, I've got an old passport somewhere in the attic with *totally unnecessary* border entry stamps (I didn't need a passport to cross that border, an ID card would have been enough). But that was pre-Schengen.

Comment: @o.m. I gathered that from your earlier comment but that's a totally different situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you wish an stamp with somehow "official" meaning. It's not so easy to get such a official stamp in the form of Heraldry (Coat of Arms), as normally such kind of stamps have serious official meaning.

As my own experience, you can get a official tourist stamp in every tourist centres, with the logo of the city tourist authorities. I used to do it a lot (But not in Copenhagen, still I think they will also kindly offer you one).

In the case of Copenhagen, you possibly could get a stamp from the tourist info with their logo: http://www.visitcopenhagen.dk/

You could get a notebook in passport form and use it to start the collection.

Some small countries do offer official passport stamps (Liechtenstein and San Marino).

Answer (score -4):

Shipping Centers like UPS,FedEX
Pharmacies like CVS,Walgreens
Retail Stores like Walmart,Target
you can go to  (http://wherecanigetstamps.com/)
it shows you any ways to buy stamps

Comment: This does not seem to be the type of stamps OP was looking for.